# Fire onTextChanged event without AutoPostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

Assume I have two text boxes, one for the `password` and one for the `password confirmation`.

Then, when I change the text in the `Confirm Password` text box, I'd like the back color of the password confirmation text box to get green or red when the confirmation is correct or incorrect.

If I use `OnTextChanged` attribute, I need to enable `AutoPostBack` which refreshes the page (something that I don't want to happen). I researched and it seems that everyone recommends Javascript, as it may somehow help.

My question is how can I perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it using javascript:

```
function compare(thisBox) {
        var targetValue = document.getElementById('passwordTextBoxClientId').value;

        if (thisBox.value === targetValue) {
            thisBox.style.backgroundColor = '#00FF00';
        }
        else {
            thisBox.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
        }
    }
```

Then  'confirm' text box should have 'onkeyup' event set:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmPassword" runat="server" onkeyup="compare(this)"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect it to be that simple.
Thanks a lot! A whole new world of posibilites :D